# How to exclude nonserializable observers from a [Serializable] INotifyPropertyChanged implementor?

Tags: c#, serialization, remoting, inotifypropertychanged

I have almost a hundred of entity classes looking like that:

```
[Serializable]
public class SampleEntity : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set { this.name = value; FirePropertyChanged("Name"); }
    }

    [field:NonSerialized]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Notice the `[field:NonSerialized]` attribute on `PropertyChanged`. This is necessary as some of the observers (in my case - a grid displaying the entities for edition) may not be serializable, and the entity has to be serializable, because it is provided - via remoting - by an application running on a separater machine.

This solution works fine for trivial cases. However, it is possible that some of the observers are `[Serializable]`, and would need to be preserved. How should I handle this?

Solutions I am considering:

- full `ISerializable` - custom serialization requires writing a lot of code, I'd prefer not to do this
- using `[OnSerializing]` and `[OnDeserializing]` attributes to serialize `PropertyChanged` manually - but those helper methods provide only `SerializationContext`, which AFAIK does not store serialization data (`SerializationInfo` does that)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're right that the first option is more work. While it can potentially give you a more efficient implementation, it will complicate your entities a lot. Consider that if you have a base `Entity` class that implements `ISerializable`, *all subclasses also have to manually implement serialization*!

The trick to getting the second option to work, is to continue marking the event as non-serializable, but to have a second field that *is* serializable and that you populate yourself during the appropriate serialization hooks. Here is a sample I just wrote to show you how:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var entity = new Entity();
            entity.PropertyChanged += new SerializableHandler().PropertyChanged;
            entity.PropertyChanged += new NonSerializableHandler().PropertyChanged;

            Console.WriteLine("Before serialization:");
            entity.Name = "Someone";

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, entity);
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                entity = binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream) as Entity;
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("After serialization:");
            entity.Name = "Kent";

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Done - press any key");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        [Serializable]
        private class SerializableHandler
        {
            public void PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Serializable handler called");
            }
        }

        private class NonSerializableHandler
        {
            public void PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  Non-serializable handler called");
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Entity : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;
        private readonly List<Delegate> _serializableDelegates;

        public Entity()
        {
            _serializableDelegates = new List<Delegate>();
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (_name != value)
                {
                    _name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
        }

        [field:NonSerialized]
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        [OnSerializing]
        public void OnSerializing(StreamingContext context)
        {
            _serializableDelegates.Clear();
            var handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                foreach (var invocation in handler.GetInvocationList())
                {
                    if (invocation.Target.GetType().IsSerializable)
                    {
                        _serializableDelegates.Add(invocation);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        [OnDeserialized]
        public void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
        {
            foreach (var invocation in _serializableDelegates)
            {
                PropertyChanged += (PropertyChangedEventHandler)invocation;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: invocation.Target can be null (for anonymous delegates), be sure to check for this

Comment: Those events have no effect on XmlSerializer (fine be me, I needed just the Remoting to work).

Comment: OnSerializing and OnDeserialized should be private, no need to expose them.

Comment: _serializableDelegates can be cleared in OnDeserialized and OnSerialized to reduce memory usage (instead of clearing in OnSerializing).

Comment: And I have to remember that the deserialized object graph contains new objects, the old references no longer work. D'oh!

Comment: +1 Good stuff Kent, helped me out on something I'm working on.