# Unserializable event handlers cannot be excluded while serialization

Tags: c#, wpf, events, serialization, mvvm

In the answer for question [How to exclude nonserializable observers from a [Serializable] INotifyPropertyChanged implementor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618994/how-to-exclude-nonserializable-observers-from-a-serializable-inotifypropertych) I found a good strategy for excluding event handlers with unserializable targets. So I used it in my code.

But while serialization the code execution seems to come suddenly into an endless loop in the `BinaryFormatter` code. This it does without any exception. If I try step-by-step execution in Visual Studio there is only a simple statement and no loop when the imaginary one is reached. All serialized objects are of one base type where the events and the serialization are defined. Additionally first the `BinaryFormatter` serializes some upper objects in the hierarchy well before reaching the loop. When it is reached, the shown `Window` content gets totally black. If I open the Parallel Threads Window while debugging there is no thread after coming into the loop.

Does anyone know which reason this has?

The code of the base class and a subbase class derived from it looks like the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[Serializable]
public class A // : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Delegate> _serializablePropertyChangedDelegates;
    private List<Delegate> _serializableSubmodelPropertyChangedDelegates;

    public A()
    {
        _serializablePropertyChangedDelegates=new List<Delegate>();
        _serializableSubmodelPropertyChangedDelegates=new List<Delegate>();
    }

    [field : NonSerialized]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [field : NonSerialized]
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler SubmodelPropertyChanged;

    [OnSerializing]
    protected void OnSerializing(StreamingContext context)
    {
        VirtualOnSerializing(context);
    }

    protected virtual void VirtualOnSerializing(StreamingContext context)
    {
        _serializablePropertyChangedDelegates=new List<Delegate>();
        if(PropertyChanged!=null)
        {
            foreach(Delegate invocation in PropertyChanged.GetInvocationList())
            {
                if((invocation.Target==null)||(invocation.Target.GetType().IsSerializable))
                {
                    _serializablePropertyChangedDelegates.Add(invocation);
                }
            }
        }
        _serializableSubmodelPropertyChangedDelegates=new List<Delegate>();
        if(SubmodelPropertyChanged!=null)
        {
            foreach(Delegate invocation in SubmodelPropertyChanged.GetInvocationList())
            {
                if((invocation.Target==null)||(invocation.Target.GetType().IsSerializable))
                {
                    _serializableSubmodelPropertyChangedDelegates.Add(invocation);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [OnDeserialized]
    protected void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        foreach(Delegate invocation in _serializablePropertyChangedDelegates)
        {
            PropertyChanged += (PropertyChangedEventHandler)(invocation);
        }
        foreach(Delegate invocation in _serializableSubmodelPropertyChangedDelegates)
        {
            SubmodelPropertyChanged += (PropertyChangedEventHandler)(invocation);
        }
    }

    // [...]
}

[Serializable]
public class B<T> : A //, INotifyCollectionChanged, IList<T>
    where T : A
{
    private List<Delegate> _serializableCollectionChangedDelegates;

    private B()
    {
        _serializableCollectionChangedDelegates=new List<Delegate>();
    }

    [field : NonSerialized]
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    protected override void VirtualOnSerializing(StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.VirtualOnSerializing(context);
        _serializableCollectionChangedDelegates=new List<Delegate>();
        if(CollectionChanged!=null)
        {
            foreach(Delegate invocation in CollectionChanged.GetInvocationList())
            {
                if((invocation.Target==null)||(invocation.Target.GetType().IsSerializable))
                {
                    _serializableCollectionChangedDelegates.Add(invocation);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [OnDeserialized]
    protected void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        base.OnDeserialized(context);
        foreach(Delegate invocation in _serializableCollectionChangedDelegates)
        {
            CollectionChanged += (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler)(invocation);
        }
    }

    // [...]
}
```

In the subclasses no other events are declared. If I do not declare the serialization methods, it works well. All other classes are derived from `A` or `B<T>`

Comment: @HansPassant: Sorry. Do you still need something else?

Comment: @HansPassant: The event handlers are only methods of the model classes derived from `A` or the not serializable view model classes derived from `ReactiveObject`. The serialized fields of the model classes are only standard value types or types derived from `A`.

Comment: Now I changed the event handler serialization conditions so that they are only true if invocation.Target.GetType() bases on `A`. So the serialization works while step-by-step debugging. But now the deserialization does not work. The corresponding methods were added to the code above.

Comment: @HansPassant The deserialization seems to work. The models work. But the view models act differently depending on whether a new main model object was created or an old one was deserialized. Changes in the models are not handled or throw errors in `ReactiveUI`. But the model is passed to the view model and the view model add the neccessary event handlers for reacting to the model. So all must be done the same way. How can this be?

Comment: You mention a problem during BinaryFormatter loop--I don't see that anywhere in your code snippet.  It's hare to tell what's going on with something if you don't provide the detail, or confirm that implementation behaviour is in fact the way you describe it...  May not be an endless loop, could be that the stream is blocked.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618994/how-to-exclude-nonserializable-observers-from-a-serializable-inotifypropertych